# Get Application badge of running applications

Tags: macos, cocoa, badge, nsapplication, nsdocktile

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to get the application badges of other running applications.  So I'd like to get the text from Mail's badge or other apps like Adium.  I've looked in `NSWorkspace` and `NSRunningApplication` and was not able to find this.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This could happen someday for applications that use NSDockTile's `setBadgeLabel:`, but, AFAIK, it's not currently possible. You might want to [file a request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

There is no way to do this to applications like Adium that composite the badged Dock icon together themselves and set it, badge and all, as a single image.